# Indefinite integral evaluation of fraction

Tags: calculus, integration

Here's the indefinite integral to evaluate:

$F(x) = \int \left(\frac{3x + 4}{x + 3}\right)dx$

Here are my steps (verbose):

$$\begin{align}
u & = x + 3 \\
(x + 3)dx & = du \\
\left(\frac{d}{dx}(x + 3)\right)dx & = du \\
\left(\frac{d}{dx}(x) + \frac{d}{dx}(3)\right)dx & = du \\
\left(\frac{d}{dx}(x) + 0\right)dx & = du \\
\left( \frac{dx}{dx} + 0 \right)dx & = du \\
(1 + 0)dx & = du \\
(1)dx & = du \\
dx & = \left( \frac{1}{1}\right)du \\
dx & = du \\
F(\ ) & = \int \left( \frac{(3x + 4)}{u} \right)du \\
u & = x + 3 \\
x + 3 & = u \\
x & = u - 3 \\
F(u)& = \int \left( \frac{3(u - 3) + 4}{u} \right)du \\
& =  \int \left( \frac{3u - 9 + 4}{u} \right)du \\
& = \int \left( \frac{3u - 5}{u} \right)du \\
& = \int \left( \frac{3u}{u} - \frac{5}{u} \right)du \\
& = \int \left( 3 - \frac{5}{u} \right)du \\
& = \int (3)du - \int \left( \frac{5}{u} \right)du \\
& = \int (3)du - 5*\int \left( \frac{1}{u} \right)du \\
& = \int (3)du - 5*ln \lvert u \rvert \\
& = \int (3*u^0)du - 5*ln \lvert u \rvert \\
& = 3*\int (u^0)du - 5*ln \lvert u \rvert \\
& = 3* \frac{1}{0 + 1}*u^{0 + 1} - 5*ln \lvert u∣ \\
& = 3* \frac{1}{1}*u^1 - 5*ln \lvert u \rvert \\
& = 3u - 5*ln \lvert u \rvert \\
u & = x + 3 \\
F(x) & = 3(x + 3) - 5*ln\lvert x + 3\rvert \\
& = 3x + 9 - 5*ln\lvert x + 3\rvert \\
& = 3x - 5*ln\lvert x + 3\rvert + 9 \\
& = \bf [3x - 5*ln\lvert x + 3\rvert + 9 + C] \\
\end{align}$$

This result agrees with both [symbolab](http://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%5Cleft(%5Cleft(3x%20%2B%204%5Cright)%2F%5Cleft(x%20%2B%203%5Cright)%5Cright)dx/?origin=button) and [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%28%283x%20%2B%204%29%2F%28x%20%2B%203%29%29dx).

Here's the solution approach provided:

Since the degree of the numerator is not less than the degree of the denominator, we must divide. A clever way to do this is shown below.

$$\begin{align}
\int \left( \frac{3x+4}{x+3} \right)dx &= \int \left( \frac{3x+9−5}{x+3} \right)dx \\
&= \int \left( \frac{3(x+3)}{x+3}  − \frac{5}{x+3} \right)dx \\
&= \int \left( 3 − \frac{5}{x+3} \right)dx \\
\end{align}$$
Now the integration is straightforward:

$\int \left(3 −​\frac{5}{x+3} \right)dx = 3x−5*ln\lvert x + 3\rvert +C$

### #

Although the partial fraction solution appears to be mathematically sound, nonetheless it loses real information: "+9"

Furthermore, I realize that if I were to take the derivative of either solution, I would end up with the same results as both constants "+9" and "C" would resolve to 0.

That stated, my concern is that using a method that is inherently prone to losing information is dangerous as it could result in actual computational error especially if instead of an indefinite integral, one was expected to evaluate a definite integral as in determining the actual area under the functions curve, in which case the missing "+9" would result in an erroneous outcome.

Would my argument above justify contesting the method provided?

Comment: Additive constant makes no difference, just rename the integration constant, $C'=C+9$. **THERE IS NO INFORMATION IN +9**.

Answer (score 3):

Nice work!

About your misgivings: Evaluating the definite integral  $F(x) \Big|_b^a$ will yield $$ 3x - 5\ln\lvert x + 3\rvert + 9 + C\Big|_b^a = \Big(3a - 5\ln|a+3| + 9 +C\Big)  - \Big( 3b - 5\ln |b + 3| + 9 + C \Big)$$

$$= 3a - 5\ln|a+3| +9 +C - 3b + 5\ln |b + 3| - 9 - C]$$

You can see that  upon simplification, we encounter $9 - 9$, $C-C$.

Constants of integration all cancel in the subtraction $F(a) - F(b)$, and as a result, they play no roll in definite integration.

Comment: Thanks for your complement, and your elegant proof. Next time I challenge a method based on a personal theory, I will go through the complete effort literally work the idea to it's conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't lose any information when you split up the equation; they are equal quantities. The fact that one method nets you a "$9+C$"  while another method only nets you another constant $"D"$ is perfectly valid. If you had initial conditions to work with, you would simply find that $9+C = D$, so your integral results are identical as well. When this type of thing happens, you can say that the $9$ was absorbed by the constant $C$. Other than that, very thorough work!